# Decay of Fourier Transform

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, asymptotics

I encountered the following statement, and I cannot see why it is true(if it is).

Suppose $f$ is a nonnegative, bounded, compactly supported and measurable function with the following properties: $||f||_1=1$, $|\widehat f(y)|<1$ for $y\neq 0$, $|\widehat f(0)|=1$ and $\frac{d}{dy}|\widehat f(y)|^2<0$.

Then, the claim which I don't quite see how it follows is the following:

For small $K$ and some $r>0$ we have $$\sup_{|y|\geq K}|\widehat f(y)|^2\leq e^{-r|K|^2}.$$

From the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma all we would get is decay of the order $1/K^2.$

Thanks

Comment: Since $|\hat{f}(y)|^2$ is decreasing, you can't have $|\hat{f}(0)| = 1$ and $|\hat{f}(y)| < 1$ for $y < 0$.

Comment: I forgot one hypothesis, we also have $||f||_1=1$ I will add this above.

Comment: That really doesn't change the issue.

Comment: Well, with that extra hypothesis we have $|\hat f(0)|=1$ and $|\hat f(y)|<1$. Maybe the last hypothesis is wrong. I think it ought to be simply $\frac{d}{dy}|\hat f(y)|<0.$ We also should assume that $f$ is non-negative.

Comment: The decreasing condition on the Fourier transform's absolute value is incompatible with the conclusion also.

Comment: The idea of _some_ sort of exponential decay is reminiscent of various versions of Paley-Wiener (-Schwartz, for distributional...) theorems, but there is a lot of extra detail here which I don't recognize. Some "uncertainty" riff, but with typose?

Comment: Yes, the third condition should be something different. It seems like what it was intended is: $\frac{d^2}{dy^2}|\hat f(y)|<0.$

Comment: @paulgarrett Do you have a good reference that talks about these versions of Paley-Wiener theorems?

Comment: Bob, most substantive "functional analysis" books would say something about Paley-Wiener (-Schwartz) theorems both in more elementary (non-distributional) and distributional contexts. The basic idea is in my course note on "Paley-Wiener theorems", linked to at the top of the page http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/  The other details in your question are still a bit mysterious to me, apart from speculations about some combination with "Heisenberg uncertainty" ideas, which are mathematically just assertions about Fourier transforms.

Comment: @paulgarrett Thank you! I will look into it!

Answer (score 2):

**Issue Resolved!**
I will post a correct statement and an answer when I have some time in the next few days!

Comment: lol....a few days^^^